# Swift 3 error while dividing in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, trigonometry

i am getting this error while trying to make a division:

*Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Int'*

```
for i in 1...40{
    let angle  = 2 * .pi / i
}
```

This code works:

```
for i in 1...40{
    let angle  = 2 * .pi / 4
}
```

Any suggestion? Maybe is something so clear that i am not seing...
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because `i` is inferred as an `Int`

Simply use  `let angle  = 2 * .pi / CGFloat(i)`

Comment: Shouldn't Swift assume that "angle" is a Double or something? seems strange that i can't divide by an Int. But anyway it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.pi` is a CGFloat, so 2 * pi is also a CGFloat. Swift prevents binary operations with several types

Answer (score 1):

The index variable is inferred as `Int` which causes the type mismatch. If it's required to be `Double` use `stride`

```
for i in stride(from: 1.0, through: 40.0, by: 1.0)  {
    let angle  = 2 * .pi / i
    print(angle)
}
```

or even annotate the floating point type

```
for i : CGFloat in stride(from: 1.0, through: 40.0, by: 1.0)  {
    let angle  = 2 * .pi / i
    print(angle)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `i` to `Double` as `i` is inferred as `Int`

```
for i in 1...40{
    let angle  = 2 * .pi / Double(i)
}
```